# proxy error econnrefused grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, gruntjs

I have ran into a problem when running through grunt.

I get a proxy error: Econnrefused when running grunt serve.

I ran --verbose too and it looks like the request is getting blocked. I think it could be related to my organisations network setup but don't know this for sure.

The web page loads but has no data etc in.

[grunt serve --verbose output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GarlH.jpg)

can anyone help please?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what this was....the second server wasn't starting correctly so the proxy had nothing to connect to. Running maven was the cause of the issues.